# Determining if the product of two particular harmonic functions is a harmonic function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, functions, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let $u$ be a $C^{2}$ harmonic function in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and let $g(x) = \left| x \right|^{2-n}$.

I would like to show that:

$v(x) = g(x)u\left(\frac{x}{\left| x \right|^{2}}\right)$

is also harmonic where it is defined, and I am wondering if there is a way to do this without explicitly showing that the Laplacian is zero.  I believe that g(x) is also harmonic and radial, but I also know that the product of two harmonic functions is not necessarily harmonic.

Comment: Did you alread verified that this functions is harmonic?

Comment: Which function(s)?  I verified $g(x)$ by hand.  $u$ is given as harmonic.  I assume that the input value for $u$ does not change that.  And the nature of the question that I'm looking seems to imply that $v(x)$ should also be harmonic.  My calculation for $g(x)$ is as follows:

Comment: Let $r = \left| x \right|, g(x) = h(r) = r^{2-n}$.  Then
$h^{\prime}(r) = (2-n)r^{1-n}$,
$h^{\prime\prime}(r) = (1-n)(2-n)r^{-n}$, and
$\Delta g(x) = h^{\prime\prime}(r) + \frac{(1-n)}{r}h^{\prime}(r) = 0$.

Comment: If $u,v\in C^2$ then $\Delta(uv)=u\Delta v+2\nabla u\nabla v+v\Delta u$. If $u,v$ are harmonic functions then $\Delta (uv)=2\nabla u\nabla v$, hence the only thinkg you need to verify in order to prove that $uv$ is harmonic, is to show that $\nabla u\nabla v=0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a clever way to solve this problme, but I don't know it. The usual solution is just use the definition which implies in calculating $\Delta v(x)$. You can try this boring calculation, or you can take a look [here](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=3&ved=0CDkQFjAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmatthewhr.files.wordpress.com%2F2012%2F09%2Fkelvin-transform.pdf&ei=cxxfUrKuFIXc9QTzy4CwBg&usg=AFQjCNFyUXsOQyA_DAx997Fh5gLu4C1Pdg&bvm=bv.54176721,d.eWU) where the calculation is made.

Comment: While the calculation in the link is helpful, it turns out that this calculation is used to show that a the inversion of a harmonic function is harmonic.  Further by pursuing more information about the Kelvin transform as mention in the link I found that a function is harmonic if and only if its inversion is harmonic.  This is exactly the information that I was seeking.  Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome